How can I ignore wildignore in Insert mode?
Is it possible to ignore wildignore for insert-mode file name completions (C-x C-f)?
I have set the wildignore to ignore most non-text files to skip them when completing in tabedit and edit commands since they can't be edited using a text-editor. But the side effect is that those files are also ignored in insert-mode completion for files. Is there a way to stop this behaviour? Or have independent ignore-list for insert-mode file name completion?

Yes you can! I use a horribly named .vim/plugin script that I wrote to save and restore wildignore during Insert mode. The code is available as part of my Dotfiles (MIT-licensed) and not as a standalone plugin.
The meat of the code is this:
augroup WIG
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter *
        \ if !exists('b:old_wildignore') |
        \   let b:old_wildignore = &wildignore |
        \   set wildignore& |
        \ endif
  autocmd InsertLeave *
        \ if exists('b:old_wildignore') |
        \   let &wildignore = b:old_wildignore |
        \   unlet b:old_wildignore |
        \ endif
augroup end

Consider adding a plugin guard if you use ~/.vim/plugin, or drop it your vimrc.

Self-promotion.

This is in-reply to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20803/2024/10/14/8-9.

To be fair, the GitHub link confused me as well. I think the answer would be better if either the link was removed (it contains little more than the code in the answer) or the authorship would be made explicit. It can be mistaken as a violation of avoid overt self-promotion.

Question asked in the chat. Answer posted in the chat.

@Friedrich is this better? (Nit: it’s not really my « product or website ». But I understand the sentiment and am happy to clarify.)

I think it's much clearer now. Also that the question came from chat. (Nit: it says "product, website, etc." where "etc." is open to interpretation.)
